# New DXWebApplication project. Resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I created a C# web application project using Dev Express's Empty Web Application Template.  When I run the project I get an error indicating the resource cannot be found.

Steps to reproduce

In VS2013
File->New->Project
From Templates->VisualC# ->Web->DevExpress v15.1 TemplateGallery

Name DXWebApplication1
With Location C:\Users\kirsten\Documents\

ASP.Net
ASP.Net MVC
Visual C#
Empty Web Application

Create Project

Build and run

The error message is

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

I am able to create an ordinary MVC application using the visual studio template successfully.  I am running Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an empty MVC project using DevExpress Template Gallery, no controllers and views are created. So, there is nothing to return. Once you created an MVC project, add a new controller with the HomeController name and the Index action and then create an Index.cshtml view in the Views/Home folder. You can also customize the default routing in the RouteConfig.cs file.

[image]